# Any PIC18F microcontroller with both CANTX, CANRX and USB D+/D-

Tags: usb, microcontroller, pic, can-bus

I found some PIC18F microncontroller (e.g. PIC18F258) with built-in CAN module. They have own CANTX and CANRX pins, which can save a lot work (without connect to other device based on SPI). I also want to transmit the CAN message into computer by USB. Thus, USB module is also necessary.
Currently, are there any PIC18F device with both built-in CAN module (CANTX,CANRX pins) and USB module (D+/D- pins)?

Comment: I think @francis is correct. I find this tool useful http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx

Comment: If you want to use 8 bit PICs another possible way is to put a USB FDTI chip to take UART to your PIC.

Comment: a reason to use usb is its high communication speed. if use FTDI to convert UART to USB signal. what will be the effect on communication speed?

Comment: You should be able to run the UART pretty fast, since you are communicating inches at best. I suspect about the speed of your operating your CANBUS .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of [pic 18f products](http://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=1004&mid=10&lang=en&pageId=74) and their specs. The `show all specs` button can be hit and the number of USB modules and the number of CAN module can be specified.

Unfortunately, there is no pic 18f microcontroller with both a USB module and a CAN module for the moment.

There are some 16-bit pic24 or dspic33 with a USB module and 2 can modules :

- dsPIC33EP256MU806
- dsPIC33EP256MU810
- PIC24EP256GU810
- dsPIC33EP256MU814
- PIC24EP256GU814
- PIC24EP512GU814
- dsPIC33EP512MU810
- PIC24EP512GU810
- dsPIC33EP512MU814

Here is the corresponding [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70616g.pdf).

Their USB module features full speed host and device support, and On The Go support.

The peripheral pin select allows you to remap the pin functions. There is no pin named CANRX or CANTX on PIC24 since you can choose input or output pins.